# Does Improved Pact Weapon only count as a focus for warlock spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, spell-components, unearthed-arcana

In Unearthed Arcana: Revised Class Options, one of the Blade pact warlock's invocations is Improved pact weapon

part of the description is:

> You can use any weapon you summon  with your Pact of the Blade feature as a spellcasting focus for your warlock spells.

does this mean if I split class into another casting class (wizard), I can't use the summoned weapon as focus for any wizard spells?

Answer (score 8):

You can only use it for warlock spells as that is what it says.

Answer (score 8):

UA classes are not balenced for multi-classing.  It isn't considered when UAs are written.

> Unearthed Arcana material isn't tuned for multiclassing.

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/841465335828041729

So, as a DM I personally wouldn't allow it, and it does indeed say "your warlock spells".